# Recover System Password Oracle XE

Tags: oracle

Recently when trying to refresh a soon to expire system password in Oracle XE I somehow locked the system account and can no longer login as "system".

How can I reset or recover this password?

Here is a console capture:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed May 10 12:32:40 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked
Enter user-name:
```

Note: I am not really a frequent user of Oracle.  I managed to google enough instructions to install and use Oracle XE enough to get by.

Currently I have one database hosted that I could erase if necessary.  Even if I have to wipe out all user data for XE and start fresh, that would be good enough.

Obviously I could try to uninstall and reinstall XE, but that seems like more work than would be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

```
C:\>set ORACLE_SID=XE
C:\>REM login as the database root account "sys"
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>alter user system account unlock;
SQL>exit
```

Comment: Still unable to connect:

    C:\Windows\system32>sqlplus / as sysdba
    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed May 10 14:14:05 2017
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    ERROR:
    ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
    Enter user-name:

Comment: Sorry that formatting is not great.  Note: I am using a shell with admin privileges on my computer.

Comment: Your user needs to be member of Windows local group "ORA_DBA"

Comment: Thanks Bjarte.  I'll try that next time.  Already reinstalled XE and got it working this time.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows, open terminal and execute this commands

`C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba`

`SQL> alter user system identified by newPassword;`

Comment: This can fail with `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.